# Issue while saving project from fott microsoft azure

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

[image]

I created the azure container in the backend and tried to save the project from fott, but while saving i'm having

> please check if you have unexpired read/write/list/delete permission
> to blob container/blob

Please help me figure out this issue.

Comment: I think the message is quite clear: check your blob parameters: "please check if you have unexpired read/write/list/delete permission to blob container/blob"

Answer (score 0):

While providing the SAS URL you only need to provide the following permissions to the container.

Read/Write/Delete/List

Here are the details from the document.

SAS URL - The shared access signature (SAS) URL of your Azure Blob Storage container. To retrieve the SAS URL, open the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, right-click your container, and select Get shared access signature. Set the expiry time to some time after you'll have used the service. Make sure the Read, Write, Delete, and List permissions are checked, and click Create. Then copy the value in the URL section. It should have the form: https://.blob.core.windows.net/?.
[image]
If the connection is successful you will be able to use the files in the container after creating a project to run OCR and label them. If the training is successful you can use this model with the analyze API.

Yutong

Comment: thanks,  actually it was the CORS issue and solved by providing parameter

Answer (score 0):

**Notes about Setting up Your Source Connection**

In order to create a new project successfully, you need to complete the following steps:

1. Enable the **Resource sharing (CORS)** of your Azure Blob Storage account.

- For this step, you can consult Microsoft's documentation: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) support for Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services#enabling-cors-for-the-azure-storage-services?WT.mc_id=udacity_learn-wwl?).

2. **Generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS)** URI to your blob container, where you will store all the training documents.

- You can check out this article: [Generate SAS tokens for storage containers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/generate-sas-tokens?WT.mc_id=udacity_learn-wwl?)

Here are some additional screenshots to help guide you a bit more.

- Enabling CORS: Under Azure Storage Account: Click on Settings > Resource sharing (CORS).
  Set the CORS rules, then "Save".
  [image]

**Important Note:**

The Azure Form Recognizer portal (https://fott-2-1.azurewebsites.net/) is a public website. Making public websites access private Azure Blob Storage resources is not a safe solution, and should only be done with your personal website to avoid security issues.

[image: Generating SAS URL]

Make sure you have uploaded files into your blob container

[image: Files uploaded to blob container]

Also read [**Best Practices When Using SAS**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#best-practices-when-using-sas)

If after all the above steps you still run into errors while creating project, try searching for your error type in a search engine and see how others have resolved the issue. For example, if you get an "Error: Check if you have unexpired read/write/list/delete permission to blob container/blob," you may find this [Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/288547/form-recognizer-error-check-if-you-have-unexpired.html?WT.mc_id=udacity_learn-wwl?) page from Microsoft helpful.